# mysql select coordinates error

Tags: php, mysql, coordinates

I am trying to get the closest coordinates from the mqysql, but getting error in the syntax !

$lat = latitude;
$long = longitude;

```
"SELECT * FROM `b_location` WHERE round(lat,3) LIKE $lat
AND round(long,2) LIKE $long order by acos(cos(radians($lat))*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(long)-
radians($long))+sin(radians($lat))*sin(radians(lat)) LIMIT 0,1"
```

error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0,1' at line 1
```

All comments are welcomed

Answer (score 1):

Missing closing bracket after the last part of the formula

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `b_location` 
 WHERE round(lat,3) LIKE $lat 
   AND round(long,2) LIKE $long 
ORDER BY acos(cos(radians($lat)) *
              cos(radians(lat)) *
              cos(radians(long) - radians($long)) +
              sin(radians($lat))*sin(radians(lat))
             ) LIMIT 0,1"
```

Comment: sometimes its the little things that matter :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

**use this for closest distance <25 **

SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;